# In Scala, does synchronized block lock all the global variables accessed in the block?

Tags: scala, concurrency

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

class MyClass {
    var globalOne = HashMap[String, String]()
    var globalTwo = HashMap[String, String]()

    def dosync(k:String, v:String) = {
        synchronized {
            globalOne = globalOne.updated(k, v)
            globalTwo = globalTwo.updated(k, v)
        }
    }
    def getKey(k:String) = {
        globalOne.get(k)
    }
}
```

Is "getKey" blocked when "dosync" is getting executed because dosync is accessing the global variables which getKey is accessing too?

Comment: Your question would be a bit clearer if you posted code that actually compiles.

Comment: @jwvh The code compiles now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: No. Moreover, it does not lock any global variables at all.

Unfortunately Scala documentation is not very rich on this topic but you can refer to the [Java documentation on synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) because it is effectively the same thing. According to the [Scala spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/12-the-scala-standard-library.html), `synchronized` comes from

```
class AnyRef extends Any {
  ...

  def synchronized[T](body: => T): T // execute `body` in while locking `this`.
}
```

It means that your

```scala
def dosync(k: SomeType, v: OtherType):Unit = {
  synchronized {
    globalOne = globalOne.put(k, v)
    globalTwo = globalTwo.put(k, v)
  }
}
```

being translated to Java is the same as

```java
public void dosync(SomeType k, OtherType v) {
  synchronized(this) {
    globalOne = globalOne.put(k, v)
    globalTwo = globalTwo.put(k, v)
  }
}
```

And here the crucial question is: What is `this` in this context? It is either an instance of a class where `dosync` or static `Class` object if `dosync` is in a simple `object`. In both of those cases `globalOne` and `globalTwo` are not "locked" in any way. Moreover, you still can do whatever you want on a "locked" object as long as you do not `synchronize` on that object. Although this is not explicitly prohibited, in most cases this is not something you really want. And this is exactly what happens in your code. Your `dosync` is synchronized over some object but `getKey` (although most probably being a part of the same `this`) is not synchronized at all and thus can access `globalOne` in an unsafe way. If you want it to be safe - you should `synchronize` inside `getKey` as well